# Quantum tunneling requirements

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, semiconductor-physics

Why does quantum tunneling require a narrow potential barrier? I mean what makes zener diodes so unique is that they dont undergo heating  because their potential barrier is very narrow.

Comment: Zener diodes obey conservation of energy, and therefore most certainly undergo heating according to the product of current and EMF.

Comment: They undergo less heating.

Comment: No, they don't. The real energy given to a component must go somewhere. Where does it go?

Comment: The electron borrows the energy and then actually i do not know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question in the first line of the question post (v1):

For a particle having energy $E$ in a potential profile $V(x)>E$, between two points $x_1$ and $x_2$, the tunneling probability (or more strictly, [the *transmission coefficient*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tunnelling)) approximately goes as 
$$T \approx \exp\left(-2 \int_{x_1}^{x_2} dx \sqrt{\frac{2m (V(x)-E)}{\hbar^2}}\right)$$
In order to decipher the underlying Physics, let us consider for simplicity a rectangular barrier for which $V(x) = V_0$ over the entire length $L = (x_2 - x_1)$. In this case, the result simplifies to 
$$T \approx \exp\left(-2 L \sqrt{\frac{2m (V_0-E)}{\hbar^2}}\right),$$
or should we say:
$$T \approx \exp(-2kL)$$
For other parameters fixed, $T$ is an exponentially decreasing function of $L$. Thus, tunneling is more likely in narrow barriers, as opposed to wider ones.

Comment: One thing to say: Lot of math and im not good at math .But i did understand what you wrote and thanks for the solution.

Comment: @MaxDestiny - You can look at the Wiki article I linked to, there is sufficient non-mathematical stuff too, over there, which can form a nice background for you, till you get to the Maths :)

Comment: I had already read the webpage info of your link before I posted my answer.